# Memcache doesn't store object properties

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I have:

```
//$this->MC->flush();
    $branchesWCounts = array();
    if (!$branchesWCounts = $this->MC->get('BRANCH_JOB_COUNT')) {
        foreach ($branches as $branch) {
            $branch->lt30min = $this->jobsAgeLessThan(1800, $branch->id);
            $branch->gt30min = $this->jobs30to120($branch->id);
            $branch->gt2hour = $this->jobs120Plus($branch->id);
            $branch->problems = $this->problemJobCount($branch->id);
            $branchesWCounts[] = $branch;
        }
        $this->MC->set('BRANCH_JOB_COUNT', $branchesWCounts);
    }
```

Which works when the cache is not there and things like 'lt30min' output correctly on my page.

But once cached it seems it can't be retrieved and seems to not exist in the cache at all.

can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Memcache won't store a PHP array. You need to store it as a string. Use [serialize()](https://www.php.net/serialize).

```
$this->MC->set('BRANCH_JOB_COUNT', serialize($branchesWCounts));
```

When getting it from Memcache, you should `unserialize()` then.